# Azure traffic manager irratic load balancing causing issues

Tags: azure, architecture, replication

I have an azure traffic manager configured to route traffic over two data centres based on performance (latency). The two DCs are replicas of each other, and is engineered in this way so that our global customers are givin a good performance no matter where they are connecting from.

The application tiers do not hold state, and the data tiers are set up using SQL merge replication on a 1 minute timer to keep the DBS in sync as to provide service continuity in the event of a Datacenter failover.

The issues that I have found is that the traffic managers routing is slightly erratic. I have observed registering a user under one Datacenter only to find the login has bee routed to the other one - the SQL replication hasn't synced at this point and the second DC isn't aware that the user exists. Even though the user both registered and logged in from the same location! The DCs are in the West US and South east asia.

I'm looking at a few options to fix this. Solution A is to Silo the users data to a specific data center, therefor whatever DC the user registers to is used thereafter. I wouldn't have syncing issues but I lose the advantage of continuity that the SQL replication provides.

Solution B is to use a different more predictable global load balancer. But first I want some opinions and to perhaps see if I am doing something wrong or perhaps my architecture is flawed.

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution had challenges using the traffic manager also, although slightly different to yours.  The traffic manager is a great value solution if it can work for you.  As far as I am aware no configuration in traffic manager allows it to be aware of sessions, therefore it is blinkered to its config setting of performance in your case.  This means its acting erratic based on your expectation for it to use sessions to be persistent to an endpoint subject to it being available.

In terms of your solution, it is very much Enterprise.  To move backwards with solution A probably doesn't fit the requirement given what you went to the effort of building.  Solution B brings many more features that Traffic Manager lacks and one of them will resolve your issue.  For other reasons I am looking at

```
 http://kemptechnologies.com/uk/server-load-balancing-appliances/virtual-loadbalancer/loadmaster-azure
```

It is designed for Azure and is available as a pre-installed VM.  There are others available but this has been my choice and what I would use if I were in your position and wanted to keep the level of resilience you currently have.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Steve - thanks for the answer, very insightful.I will be looking at implementing this and will report back on the results.
Separately, is the load balancer free? It says 'free for Azure' but I'm a bit sceptical.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you could rate the answer when convenient it would be much appreciated.  The price depends on your throughput and endpoints, for my solution the free version is adequate and fully functional.  The cost is the VM running it but my tested version is very happy on a very small VM.  There are guides online about configuring it but the staff at Kemp were very helpful to me.  Remember you need at least two, one for each DC and you can create resilient pairs like physical devices.  Also watch out for your networks, as it works on IP so you need endpoints in the same network.

Comment: Just to update this answer - this is what I ended up using, and the KEMP guys are very very helpful in getting set up. The product is comprehensive in providing a production ready alternative to Azure traffic manager with a huge amount of additional functionality/features.